# (unity 2D) I want to add knockback to my entire player when he shoots

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

I want to add knockback where he is aiming so the player can propulse with his own bullets. But I dont know how to add force in the direction my gun is aiming.

Comment: Welcome to [es.so] Official langugage in this site is Spanish. You should translate your question or post it on [so]